# How can I "refresh" the last line of output in terminal, if I want to use a pretty-printing library to add colours?

Tags: haskell, terminal, pretty-print

There is a program that interacts with the user by repeatedly overwriting the last line of text in `stderr`. It is done as follows:

- There is a state monad that remembers the length of the last line printed.
- When It wants to overwrite a line `s` with another line `s'`, It pads `s'` with spaces until it is at least as long as `s` and prepends it with *"carriage return"* character:

  ```
  n <- gets lastLineLength
  let s'Padded | 0 < n     = '\r': s' ++ replicate (n - length s') ' '
               | otherwise = s'
  hPutStr stderr s'Padded
  ```

This works just fine. *(Though I personally have not tested it in circumstances other than the usual Linux terminal.)*

I set about improving this program by replacing plain `String` by a `Doc` type from [`ansi-wl-pprint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-ANSI-Leijen-Internal.html) so that I may paint the text in colours, in the same fashion as the recent GHC sports. A library such as this one may be overkill, as I only need to output a few lines at once, and without any indentation, but I wanted to give it a try for its abstract colouring facilities. However, I don't think this library (or any pretty printing library for that matter) would feature a function aimed at erasing previously printed `Doc`s.

One solution I have in mind is rendering the `Doc` to a `String` and measuring its length. However, I will have to discount for colour codes; furthermore, this is overall an intrusion into the abstraction the library offers: specifically, I will have to rely on the assumption that the render I do manually will match the render implicitly done by `hPutDoc`.

Should I forfeit the library altogether and keep dealing in `String`s, manually throwing in ANSI escape sequences and carriage returns? Is there a nicer way to overwrite previous output? I welcome any advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ansi-wl-pprint` depends on `ansi-terminal`, which has a [`clearLine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.8.0.1/docs/System-Console-ANSI.html#v:clearLine) method and other utilities to move around and record positions in the console.

Under the hood, `clearLine` sends a specific *ANSI control sequence* to erase the current line. There is also a control sequence to rewind the cursor to the beginning of the current line (or any line, for that matter). This is somewhat an obscure art, but you'd be surprised to see [how many control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) there are.

You can manipulate the control sequences manually. For example, if you `putStr "\ESC[2K\ESC[0G"`, it should erase the current line and then put the cursor to the beginning of it − analogous to what your code is doing, but cleaner. But it would probably serve you best if you depend on `ansi-terminal` and use the operations `hClearLine` and `hSetCursorColumn` defined there. If ou already indirectly depend on `ansi-terminal` through `ansi-wl-pprint`, it should not incur additional build time cost.